# Replace element with razor textarea

Tags: razor

I want to take a  tag and replace with a @Html.textarea() razor html helper but it doesn't look as if JQuery can replace DOM elements with html helpers. How do I go about this?

```
using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
<a id="clickme">Edit</a>
<div>@Model.username</div> 
}
```

How can I replace this div with @Html.Textarea ? JQuery could do it with div and input tags.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot replace a tag with @Html.TextArea() !

The `TextArea` helper method is a C# method, which gets executed when razor tries to render the view. This happens in your web server. jQuery is a client side library and anything you do with jQuery happens at client side, in your browser.

But all these helper methods ultimately generate some HTML for DOM elements. That means, you can use jQuery to manipulate visibility of that.

If you are trying to do something like an inline edit, you can use a script like this , to start with

First, render the text area along with your label div, but have it hidden initially. Also wrap the label,edit link and the hidden input inside a container div which we can use later to help with our jQuery selectors.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="edit-item">
        <a  href="#" data-mode="label">Edit</a>
        <div class="edit-label">@Model.FirstName</div>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.FirstName, 
                           new { style = "display:none;", @class = "edit-text" })
    </div>

    <div class="edit-item">
        <a  href="#" data-mode="label">Edit</a>
        <div class="edit-label">@Model.UserName</div>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.UserName,
                         new { style = "display:none;", @class = "edit-text" })
    </div>
}
```

Now when the user clicks edit, you have to toggle the visibility of the label and hidden input and update the value of label after user done editing the value in the input element.

```
$(function () {

    $("a[data-mode]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);
        var c = _this.closest(".edit-item");
        c.find(".edit-text").toggle();
        c.find(".edit-label").toggle();

        if (_this.attr("data-mode") === 'label') {
            _this.attr("data-mode", 'edit');
            _this.text("done");
        } else if (_this.data("mode") === 'edit') {
            c.find(".edit-label").text(c.find(".edit-text").val());
            _this.text("edit");
            _this.attr("data-mode", 'label');
        }
    });

});
```

This is a head start. You can optimize this code as needed.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qisulokase/1/edit?html,output) is a working jsfiddle for your reference